# SQL server 2008 enterprise installation error on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

When I try to install SQL Server 2008 enterprise on my Windows 7 machine, I get this error message. When I click on `Retry`, I get the same error again.

> Error reading from file F:\SQL2008\Enterprise\X86\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\MSSQL.X\MSSQL\Binn\8b0t4lpp.mof. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

How can I to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try different install media; sounds like that one's scratched (or, if a mounted ISO, corrupt).

And, while you're trying things, some advice...

1. Don't install SQL Server Enterprise on a Windows 7 machine.  No good can come of it.

   - If you must use Windows 7, use SQL Express.  Using SQL Server Enterprise on Windows 7 is going to be a waste of a very expensive license, because the limits of the Windows 7 OS will render the more advanced features of SQL Server Enterprise useless.
   - Why install a 32 bit version of SQL Server?  Unless you have a good reason not to, use the 64 bit version instead.
2. Don't try to use a Windows 7 OS as a server operating system, because it's not. Use a real server OS instead.

   - Things like sparsely documented concurrent connection and user limits will make this a nightmare.